# Linking identifiers across tables in MySQL (Foreign Keys)

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Given a simplified example of two tables

```
table Contact(ID int primary key, Name text not null)
table ContactPhone(ContactID int not null, PhoneNumber text not null)
```

Is there a way to tell MySQL that the `ContactPhone.ContactID` field is referencing the Primary Key of `Contact`?

Can there be automatic handling? If the Contact is deleted, then relevant `ContactPhone.ContactID` should be set to zero.

Ideally this flag/code/operation should be attached to the `ContactPhone` table. This way existing software that interacts with the `Contact` table can keep on the way it is, and the `ContactPhone` table and related software can be added or removed as one unit, without the necessity of altering the `Contact` table.

Specifically I want to be able to be able to empty out the `Contact` table, reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `=1`, and bring in new `Contact`s AND I don't want to have to tell this program anything about `ContactPhone`. I want it to be automatic.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to tell MySQL that the ContactPhone.ContactID field is referencing the Primary Key of Contact?

Yes, use a foreign key.

> Can there be automatic handling? If the Contact is deleted, then relevant ContactPhone.ContactID should be set to zero.

Yes, add in an action after `ON DELETE` in the below code.

Here's an example:

```
create table ContactPhone(
  ContactID int not null, 
  PhoneNumber text not null,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contactid`      -- this is the foreign key
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContactID` )
    REFERENCES `Contact`(`id` )
    ON DELETE <some action>      -- the on delete action goes here
) engine = InnoDB;               -- make sure to use InnoDB if you want FKs to be enforced
```

Make sure that either `InnoDB` is specified as the storage engine, or that your version of MySQL defaults to `InnoDB`.  Other storage engines will parse and silently ignore foreign key constraints.

Here's the grammar for a [MySQL foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Foreign Keys only work in InnoDB. MyISAM ignores them.

Comment: Presumably the referential triggered action they require is `ON DELETE SET NULL` which you do not mention.

Comment: @DTest -- good point, updated post to reflect that.